# how to use Pycharm as use in Jupyter Notebook to read an object that stored in the ram?

Tags: python, pycharm

Every time I want to view a df in Pycharm, I need to select from the beginning to the specific line of reading the df, and it takes time to run it every time. I want to view it as variables but no variables are found in the IDE. Thanks.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Are you working in a debug environment? In a console? Try to be more clear what exactly the problem is and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, the scenario is that after importing some packages and df = pd.read_csv, the df variable is not found anywhere, no matter in console or debug environment

Comment: It is a little hard to help without more details. If I just create a simple Dataframe in the Pycharm's console, it appears in the Variables window... Try to be more clear as to how you run the code and what you expect to find. (Maybe even attach code...)

Comment: ok, maybe i should stake like this: after I click the run button, the variables will not be stored unless I type manually in the console. Is there any way to show the variables after clicking the run button? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make PyCharm Python console work with code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017510/how-to-make-pycharm-python-console-work-with-code)

Comment: Another possible option depending on your needs is simply using `debug` instead of `Run`. You will need to put some breakpoints to be able to observe your data